# Can not remove folder

Tags: python, directory, shutil, removeall

I have folder which contains a some files checked out from SVN. So it contains a `.svn` hidden file also.

I used shuttle remove directory, please see below code.

```
import shutil

path = "D:/Project/Myfolder"
shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
```

The above code successfully deleted all contents from the folder except `.svn`. How do I remove the entire directory(Including folder)

Comment: What are the permissions of the `.svn` folder? `shutil` documentation has example that suggests e.g. readonly files on Windows cannot be normally deleted - https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#rmtree-example

Answer (score 0):

[Shutil Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#rmtree-example)

As per the above shutil documentation is working.

```
import os, stat
import shutil

def remove_readonly(func, path, _):
    "Clear the readonly bit and reattempt the removal"
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
    func(path)

shutil.rmtree(directory, onerror=remove_readonly)
```

Thank you @h4z3